# Gatsby with CDN reference

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, google-fonts

I'm trying to get bootstrap.css and Google fonts CDNs working in my Gatsby project.

There is no HTML file; just JavaScript files.

For bootstrap, I can `npm install bootstrap` and then import the `min.css` from that.

Trying to figure out how to get `Amatic SC` font from Google fonts; I have `npm` installed `google-fonts-webpack-plugin`.

I am using `gatsby-node.js` by adding:

```
const GoogleFontsPlugin = require("google-fonts-webpack-plugin")

exports.modifyWebpackConfig = ({ config, stage }) => {

    config.plugin("google-fonts-webpack-plugin",new GoogleFontsPlugin(
        {
            fonts: [
                { family: "Amatic SC" }
            ]
        }
    ),null)

};
```

However, I get the error below;

> Invalid 'constructor' parameter. You must provide either a function or null

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Is there a way of referencing a CDN directly so rather than `npm` installing bootstrap, I could just reference its latest version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can include the font using [typeface-amatic-sm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-amatic-sc) from NPM, and in your JS do:

```
import 'typeface-amatic-sc'
```

Otherwise, can include scripts it in your `</head>` using [helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) like:

```
<Helmet>    
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: ok thanks. I will try that.
Any idea why my approach doesn't work? Just interested because it will probably help me avoid the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I have to add in all files if I have to use this solution or there is smart work to do?